# Draw text with Python in 3d coordinate system

Tags: python

I know that I can use the `blf` module to draw 2d text, but is there a method to draw text at certain positions in 3d space?

I want to add a text right to a specific point in 3d.

Comment: Do you mean on the 2D projection of a 3D location, as in, for example, the MeasureIt  addon, or in full perspective? Or.. in perspective, but always facing the viewpoint?

Comment: Thx, I found an example in the MeasureIt addon

Comment: @RobinBetts can set `blf.rotation(..)` (and aspect) to rotate text on screen.  I remember fiddling with this and accidentally rotated all the GUI text too. (oops meant to comment under answer comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thx, I found an example in the MeasureIt addon and here is some code from my Fast Carve addon to draw 2d text:

```
rv3d = self._view_context.region_3d
region = self._view_context.region
pos_text = location_3d_to_region_2d(region, rv3d, self._center)

blf.position(2, pos_text[0], pos_text[1], 0)
blf.draw(2, "r: {0:.3f}".format(self._radius))
```

Comment: I was hoping you would ;) ... perhaps, if there's a short enough chunk of code to clue other readers in, you could paste it into your answer, to make it 'BSE complete'

Comment: @RobinBetts: I added the Python snippet from my addon

Comment: Hi @Jayanam can you share full script because I have the [same question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193334/how-can-i-make-a-custom-gizmo-with-opengl?noredirect=1#comment324022_193334)

Comment: The full script is here: https://github.com/jayanam/jmesh-tools/blob/master/types/circle_shape.py

Answer (score 0):

This is a script that adds text at position x,y,z and the text says "my text"

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(x,y,z))
ob=bpy.context.object
ob.data.body = "my text"
```