# How can I make a custom gizmo with OpenGL?

Tags: python

I made a custom gizmo with OpenGL

[image]

I want to do something after clicking on points like `print("Hello World")` and change the color of selected point.

[image]

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras import batch
import bgl
from random import random


positions = (
    (-1, -1, -1), (+1, -1, -1),
    (-1, +1, -1), (+1, +1, -1),
    (-1, -1, +1), (+1, -1, +1),
    (-1, +1, +1), (+1, +1, +1))
    
colors = (
    (1, 1, 1,1), (1, 1, 1,1),
    (1, 1, 1,1), (1, 1, 1,1),
    (1, 1, 1,1), (1, 1, 1,1),
    (1, 1, 1,1), (1, 1, 1,1))

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin("3D_FLAT_COLOR")
batch = batch.batch_for_shader(shader, "POINTS", {"pos": positions, "color": colors})

def draw():
    shader.bind()
    bgl.glPointSize(5)
    batch.draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), "WINDOW", "POST_VIEW")
```

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193145/how-can-i-make-a-custom-gizmos-to-set-the-origin

Comment: Hi @batFINGER this question is different I just want to know is it possible to use raycast to select the OpenGL points?

Comment: A solution with no raycast is effectivelly in the code indicated by @batFINGER. lines 105/110.

Comment: @lemon hmmm do you mean Find the closest corner using a dot product from the view. I actually confused by that code because it was complex so I tried to find the easy way.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali, yes dot product: the bigger, the closest. Then just tune the limit (ie 0.999). And raycast means creating surfaces (so more code to do it).

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali similarly  as  if your point shares the same 2d coord as the mouse (or close enough)  Can see no evidence in question re it being about raycasting,  Is it supposed to be easy? Have offered this advice before, for say an hour, disconnect from the internet and resist the urge to ask another question here (or via comment) until you understand how something works.  If need be add some print statements to see the values. Resist the urge on getting  an error and posting  "_I tried .... It doesn't work_".  The fine line between seeking answers and just wanting them given to you.

Comment: @batFINGER you are right I shouldn't ask what I want. I should try harder to solve the problem myself because when I solve the problem my self I will learn a lot but if someone solve my problem I won't learn.I'm really sorry. thank you for the advice you're great!